# Entity Framework 6 and output parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, output, entity-framework-6

First time working with EF in general and wanted to call a stored procedure. 
So far I've added the stored procedure in a model (.edmx) and I believe that it's calling properly but I'm not sure how to add the output parameter.

This is what the stored procedure is accepting:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProperty__Read] 
@Skip           INT = NULL,
@Take           INT = NULL,
@OrderBy        VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Return_Code        INT = 0 OUTPUT
```

I thought I could do this with the output parameter:

```
  var returnCode = new SqlParameter();
  returnCode.ParameterName = "@ReturnCode";
  returnCode.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
  returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  var results = context.uspProperty__Read(10, 10, "NameDesc", out returnCode );
```

It looks like I've set the stored procedure correctly because "uspProperty_Read" comes up with the intellisense.

[image: Error Message]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this one? [How to: Execute a Parameterized Stored Procedure Using EntityCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896274(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ObjectParameter instead of SqlParameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That resolved the issue. 
I can't believe I didn't look for ObjectParameter when it was staring in my face. Thanks again!